# MySQL read replica on Same Server Using mysqld_multi Error mysqld: Can't create directory '/var/lib/mysql_replica/' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)

Tags: mysql, permissions, database-replication

I'm trying to get a read replica on my Ubuntu 22.04 server. I'm going off of this article:
[MySQL Master-Slave Replication on the Same Machine](https://www.toptal.com/mysql/mysql-master-slave-replication-tutorial). I'm getting stuck on [Installation of the Second MySQL Instance](https://www.toptal.com/mysql/mysql-master-slave-replication-tutorial#installation-of-the-second-mysql-instance); the article references `mysql_install_db`, which as I understand, has been deprecated in MySQL 8

I'm using: `mysql  Ver 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`

---

> ***My question***: On 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2, how do I resolve permission
> issues so that I can install my second MySQL instance in
> /var/lib/mysql_replica

---

When I run the following:

```
sudo mysqld --initialize --user=mysql --basedir=/var/lib/mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql_replica
```

I get this error:

```
sudo mysqld --initialize --user=mysql --basedir=/var/lib/mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql_replica/
mysqld: Can't create directory '/var/lib/mysql_replica/' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2023-07-08T11:40:34.102368Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) initializing of server in progress as process 92415
2023-07-08T11:40:34.102400Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010338] [Server] Can't find error-message file '/var/lib/mysql/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'. Check error-message file location and 'lc-messages-dir' configuration directive.
2023-07-08T11:40:34.103522Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql_replica/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2023-07-08T11:40:34.103809Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-07-08T11:40:34.104059Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2)  (Ubuntu).
```

I've tried removing / recreating the directory, adding ubuntu to the mysql user group, & setting the permissions & re-running, but to no avail; I get the same error as above

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql_replica
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql_replica
sudo usermod -aG mysql ubuntu
sudo chown -R ubuntu:mysql /var/lib/mysql_replica
sudo chmod 750 /var/lib/mysql_replica
```

When I tail the AppArmor log the following I get:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep -i apparmor
Jul  8 11:40:29 ip-#-#-#-# kernel: [514029.361780] audit: type=1400 audit(1688816429.849:66): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=92405 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul  8 11:40:29 ip-#-#-#-# kernel: [514029.361785] audit: type=1400 audit(1688816429.849:67): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/{,usr/}sbin/dhclient" pid=92405 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul  8 11:40:29 ip-#-#-#-# apparmor.systemd[92410]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.mysqld
Jul  8 11:40:29 ip-#-#-#-# apparmor.systemd[92411]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Jul  8 11:40:29 ip-#-#-#-# systemd[1]: Reloaded Load AppArmor profiles.
Jul  8 11:50:38 ip-#-#-#-# kernel: [514638.054645] audit: type=1400 audit(1688817038.472:73): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/var/lib/mysql_replica/" pid=92478 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jul  8 11:51:01 ip-#-#-#-# kernel: [514661.361667] audit: type=1400 audit(1688817061.778:74): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/var/lib/mysql_replica/" pid=92504 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jul  8 11:51:49 ip-#-#-#-# kernel: [514709.257782] audit: type=1400 audit(1688817109.664:75): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/var/lib/mysql_replica/" pid=92529 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=1000
Jul  8 11:56:10 ip-#-#-#-# kernel: [514970.372665] audit: type=1400 audit(1688817370.749:76): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mkdir" class="file" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/var/lib/mysql_slave/" pid=92569 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

As per [Additional Security Settings in AppArmor](https://www.toptal.com/mysql/mysql-master-slave-replication-tutorial#iadditional-security-settings-in-apparmor) in the article, I've updated `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` with:

```
/var/lib/mysql_replica/ r,
/var/lib/mysql_replica/** rwk,
/var/log/mysql_replica/ r,
/var/log/mysql_replica/* rw,
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld_replica.pid rw,
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld_replica.sock w,
/run/mysqld/mysqld_replica.pid rw,
/run/mysqld/mysqld_replica.sock w,
```

- I've run `sudo systemctl reload apparmor` & `sudo systemctl status apparmor`
- I've also tried disabling AppArmor `sudo systemctl stop apparmor`

At this point, I'm at a loss; I know there's a permission issue, I just don't understand what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

...and the typical facepalm moment came shortly after posting

I needed to run `sudo reboot`

Now this works: `sudo mysqld --initialize --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql_replica`